# Docker don't create volume

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, telebot

Я делаю бота с pyTelegramBotAPI и использую docker. Образы и контейнеры собираются хорошо и мой бот работает в докер контейнере и его видно в самом телеграме. Но я хочу сделать 'hot change' (в случае изменения кода - докер контейнер будет обновляться автоматически). Похоже что проблема в Volume потому что когда я пытаюсь посмотреть `docker volume ls` возвращается пустой лист. С самим докером проблем нет, другие приложения собираются нормально, volume создаются. Я запускаю сборку командой `docker-compose up --build`

Мой Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers 


COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . /app/
```

Мой docker-compose.yml. main.py - это главный фаил телеграм бота. Портов и хостов здесь не пробрасывал.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  bot:
    build: .
    command: python main.py
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

Comment: Hi, this is ruSO, and all questions should be asked only in Russian

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Напишите что вы конкретно делаете. Как именно пробуете делать `hot change`? Получаете ли при этом ошибки? Сейчас не ясно ни что не работает ни какие симптомы, поэтому помочь будет затруднительно. Используйте кнопку "править", чтоб уточнить вопрос и добавить недостающую информацию.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Изменяю сам функционал бота (например приветственное сообщение). Но проблема не в этом. Даже volume не создается, который бы подхватывал папку на хосте и направлял ее в докер контейнер.

Answer (score 0):

У вас написано:

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
```

Именованый volume делается так: `- data:/data` -- `/data` внутри соответствует volume-у `data`. Но, для этого вопроса оно не надо.

Вам надо, чтобы папка с кодом на хосте соответствовала чему-то внутри:
 `- .:/app`.
Это эначит `/app` внутри соответствует текущей папке на хосте.
Это не именованый volume, и `docker volume ls` его не покажет.

Предполагается, что код в текущей папке вместе с `docker-compose.yml`.

Теперь, если под поменять, внутри будут видны изменения.

Дальше смотрите, как делать ваш 'hot change'. Это зависит от фреймворка.

Если руками, то можно, чтоб сама программа раз в секунду проверяла дату изменения  своего исходника в `/app`, и делала exit. A докер ее переподнимал.